# Bash, pipe parse and format json (slim it down)

Tags: json, linux, macos, bash, unix

I have a bash script that outputs a json like this:

```
 {
    "name": "some",
    "desc": "this is a desc",
    "env": "this is an env type",
    "dd": {
        "one": "rr",
        "two": "aa"
    },
    "url": "http://someurl",
    //etc......
}
```

I would like to pipe a new command in my script, to return the final json output as:

```
{
    "name": "some",
    "env": "this is an env type",
    "dd": {
        "one": "rr",
        "two": "aa"
    }
}
```

How can i achieve this **without installing new tools/libs like jq** etc..

Any clue?

Comment: so basically write a json parser using nothing but bash? wouldn't it be easier to just output the json in the format you want in the first place? you shouldn't be mangling json after it's formed anyways.

Comment: The problem is that the json contains many keys i don't need , i just would like to slim it down with a new command, cause sometimes it could be MB  @Marc B

Comment: so... again, why not fix the script that builds the json in the first place? you don't go to the grocery store, buy the ENTIRE store's inventory, truck it home, then rummage around and throw away everything except the carrot you wanted.

Comment: `jq` is a standalone executable so it doesn't really need to be installed. I'd say it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Marc B because is not a script i wrote, it's an external tool i can't touch it actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you've stipulated that you do this without external tools but hopefully this will change your mind:

```
jq '{ name, env, dd }' file.json
```

That was easy!

[`jq` is very easy to obtain](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/).

A quick and dirty python script would also work:

```
import sys
import json

with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
    obj = json.load(file)
    print json.dumps({ key: obj[key] for key in ("name", "env", "dd") })
```

It can be run like `python script.py file.json`. To improve the formatting, you can pass extra arguments to `json.dumps` ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)).

Comment: I am on osx Yosemite and i get `jq: command not found` i would not install anything

Comment: I've linked to the download page. I really think this is the best way to go.

Comment: Ofc is the best but not the one i am looking for :(

Comment: install [homebrew](http://brew.sh) and then you just need to do `brew install jq` and you'll have it.

Comment: @sbaaaang I added a simple python option that you could go for.

Comment: @sbaaaang If `bash` is your customer's requirement, then you need to convince them that `bash` alone is not suitable for processing JSON. If `bash` is your choice, you need to pick another language. You aren't doing them any favors by providing a substandard solution using insufficient tools.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i achieve this without installing new tools/libs like jq etc..
>   Any clue?

Well, to make an analogy it's like you were asking "how can I become a world champion in 100m sprint run, but I have no legs and I want no fake legs". The simple answer is that you cannot, or if you do, it won't be flexible and generic enough to be really useful.

Doing shell scripting is like having a toolbox, with many tools, each being designed to do one task and do it well. So if you refuse the tool that might be the right thing for what you need, then you cannot do it.

So the right way to do it is to use a tool such as `jq`, or a small python/ruby/... script that will take keys out of your json data.

Comment: No legs sounds a lot restrictive :P

Comment: no tools like `jq` sounds a lot restrictive as well :-)

Comment: eheheh but man, this script has to run on customers machine, i can't install new tools

Comment: would you consider doing shell scripting and getting rid of `grep`, `sed` or `cut` etc..?

Comment: bring the tool along with the script then, or do it in python (which has a json parser module shipped per default)

Comment: python sounds good, do you even know if it's native both on osx and linux ? how can i check python support for each OS ?

Comment: if your issue really is only not installing new tools, then use something like python or ruby to do it, as they're shipped with a json parser. If you really want to stick with bash, then use jq, even if you need to ship the tool with the script. Otherwise the conditions you're giving are mutually exclusive, and thus not possible.

Comment: python has been shipped on OSX per default for the last 15 years. And afaict, all linux distributions ship a python interpreter.

Comment: thank you a lot for the  suggestions! i will try something in the meantime